# How to display values using three different Tables Using Access

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
OleDbDataAdapter dt = new OleDbDataAdapter("select UserName from UserInfo where User_ID = (select User_ID from Groupmem_info where Group_ID=(select Group_Member_ID from GroupInfo where Group_ID ='" + grp.Text + "'", con);
```

Can we use this sort of code in access where I need to display user name from three linked tables. Mutual id's of group and user will be in Group Members Information Table.

Please suggest how to retrieve User name and I want to display all user names in `datagridview`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more efficient approach would be to change the SQL statement to an inner join and use parametrized queries to avoid SQL Injection attacks:

```
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
OleDbCommand command;

// Create the SelectCommand.
command = new OleDbCommand("select UserName from UserInfo ui  join Groupmem_info gi on ui.User_ID =ui.User_ID where gi.Group_ID = ? ", con);

command.Parameters.Add("GroupID", OleDbType.Integer);//assuming it's an integer
adapter.SelectCommand = command;
```

Now you can call `Fill` on the `OleDbDataAdapter` and set the `DataSource` property of the grid to whatever table you filled in:

```
youGrid.DataSource=yourDataTable;
```

Comment: thanks a lot lcarus. i am really glad to hear this approach helped me a lot.